# Laravel Form::select shows nothing

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi I'm using Laravel version 5.6 and got a problem in view with Form::select.

I already made some Form::open with 'text' and 'textarea' they all worked fine, but the Form::select do not generate the select fild on my view.

I used this code:

`{!! Form::label('isPropaganda', 'Propaganda:') !!}
{!! Form::select('isPropaganda', ['Não' => '0', 'Sim' => '1'], null, ['class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}`

I found the example here http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field but didn't workout. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping the keys and values. Keys cannot have special characters in them. Also, I'm not sure what that 'multiple' attribute is doing there. If it's meant to be a css class, place it inside the 'class' array key, otherwise add it to a new attributes array.

```
{!! Form::select('isPropaganda', ['0' => 'Não', '1' => 'Sim'], null, ['class'=>'form-control multiple']) !!}
```

Comment: I tried with and without the 'multiple' argument in the form control, with and without the 'null' argument nothing worked. None of this show some select box.